# Numpy: Why is numpy.array([2]).any() > 1 False?

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.array([2]) > 1
array([ True], dtype=bool)
>>> numpy.array([2]).any() > 1
False
```

Shouldn't any() test all elements of the array and return True?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does return True. But (True > 1) == False. While the first part is 2 > 1 which of course is True.

As others posted, you probably want:

```
(numpy.array([2])  > 1).any()
```

Comment: to be exact: `numpy.array([2]).any()` returns `True`

Comment: So any() should only be used on booleans. I get the idea now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are confusing it with this

```
>>> (numpy.array([2]) > 1).any()
True
```